# Menu is created, but disappears after navigations

Tags: xamarin, menu, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I created menu in Xamarin Android application. It is showing on first page, but after PushAsync it disappears. Also after returning to first page it is not showing any more. Here is a code:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IOnMenuItemClickListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.action_menu);
        toolbar.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
    {
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ...
    private async void OnSecondPageClicked()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
    }
}
```

File action_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="new_game"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="help"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mixture of a Xamarin.Android app and a Xamarin.Forms app. This answer assumes you want a forms app. You should remove the following lines from OnCreate

```
var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.action_menu);
toolbar.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
```

And add these lines to the constructor of MainPage

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("New Game", "", () => { }));
this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Help", "", () => { }));
```

If that works you should move MainPage and App into your Cross Platform project.

Comment: I did want forms app. Thank you for your answer.